# S3 Multipart upload in Chunks

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-requests, boto3

I am trying to upload a file from a url into my s3 in chunks, my goal is to have python-logo.png in this example below stored on s3 in chunks image.000 , image.001 , image.002 etc. i have the below code but i am getting error `ValueError: Fileobj must implement read` can some one point me out to what i am doing wrong? please not the actual data i am trying to upload is much larger, this image file is just for example.

```
import threading
import requests
import boto3
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig

bucket_name = "bucket-name-here"

def multi_part_upload_with_s3():
    # Multipart upload
    config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=100000, max_concurrency=80,
                            multipart_chunksize=100000, use_threads=True)
    url = "https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo.png"
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    session = boto3.Session()
    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    key = 'brokenup/image.'
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
    num = 0
    for chunk in r.iter_content(100000):
        file = key+str(num).zfill(3)
        num += 1
        bucket.upload_fileobj(chunk, file, Config=config, Callback=None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for `upload_fileobj`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj) states:

> Upload a file-like object to S3.
>
> The file-like object must be in binary mode.

In other words, you need a binary file object, not a byte array.  The easiest way to get there is to wrap your byte array in a `BytesIO` object:

```python
from io import BytesIO
...
        bucket.upload_fileobj(BytesIO(chunk), file, Config=config, Callback=None)
```

Comment: Thank you. Ur comment solved my issue. another question if you may help, what do you think about my TransferConfig logic here and is it working with the chunking? i am getting slow upload speeds, how can i improve this logic?

Comment: You're not using file chunking in the sense of S3 multi-part transfers at all, so I'm not surprised the upload is slow.  To my mind, you would be much better off upload the file as is in one part, and let the TransferConfig use multi-part upload.  If on the other side you need to download part of a file, use ByteRange requests

Comment: for my usecase i need the file to be broken up on S3 as such! is it possible to fix it where S3 multi-part transfers is working with chunking. possibly multiple threads uploading many chunks at the same time? sorry i am new to all this, thanks for the help

Comment: If you really need the separate files, then you need separate uploads, which means you need to spin off multiple worker threads to recreate the work that boto would normally do for you.  I'd suggest looking into the `threading` library, or perhaps the `ThreadPoolExecutor` helper.